# Simple hello world api using finagle - Error: object twitter is not a member of package com import com.twitter.finagle.Http

Tags: scala, rest, twitter, microservices, finagle

Im really new to this microservice world and was trying to learn from scratch. But for some reason not able to call a simple dependency.

Getting the error

> object twitter is not a member of package com import
> com.twitter.finagle._

SBT file, Ive tried three ways

Trial 1

```
name := "microservicestest"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.15"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-core" % "0.31.0",
  "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-circe" % "0.31.0",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.9.0"
)
```

Trial 2 (puttting just the dependency line in here)

```
libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" %% "finagle-http" % "21.8.0"
```

Trial 3

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-core" % "0.15.1"
)
```

Scala file

```
import io.finch._
import com.twitter.finagle.Http
import com.twitter.util.Await

object HelloWorld extends App {
  val api: Endpoint[String] = get("hello") { Ok("Hello, World!") }
  Await.ready(Http.server.serve(":8080", api.toServiceAs[Text.Plain]))
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Do you run an SBT command?

Comment: yes, while building it.

Comment: Just one minor observation: your error states `object twitter is not a member of package com import com.twitter.finagle._`, and yet you do not actually have an import statement in your example that reads `import com.twitter.finagle._`. It seems that there's something missing here: can you post the entire output from when you run sbt?

Comment: Yes I missed that line. Well I got a simple code working in sbt. Now im struggling in creating a bazel project. Will close this and create a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270842/error-object-service-is-not-a-member-of-package-com-twitter-finagle-defining

Answer (score 0):

SBT file

```
libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" %% "finagle-http" % "21.8.0"
```

Working simple code

```
import com.twitter.finagle.{Http, Service}
import com.twitter.finagle.http
import com.twitter.util.{Await, Future}

object HelloWorld extends App {
  val service = new Service[http.Request, http.Response] {
    def apply(req: http.Request): Future[http.Response] =
      Future.value(http.Response(req.version, http.Status.Ok))
  }
  val server = Http.serve(":8080", service)
  Await.ready(server)
}
```