# error: object Service is not a member of package com.twitter.finagle - Defining Bazel dependencies in Build file, Scala finagle

Tags: scala, sbt, bazel, finagle, bazel-rules

Im trying to add the finagle-http library to my new bazel project as an external maven dependency. But getting the following error. I assume im doing something wrong in creating the build without fully understanding it. Trying to learning. Appreciate any help on this.

```
error: object Service is not a member of package com.twitter.finagle
error: object util is not a member of package com.twitter
error: type Request is not a member of package com.twitter.finagle.http
error: object Response is not a member of package com.twitter.finagle.http
error: Symbol 'type com.twitter.finagle.Client' is missing from the classpath. This symbol is required by 'object com.twitter.finagle.Http'.
error: not found: value Await
```

The same code is working using sbt. Below is the code.

```
import com.twitter.finagle.{Http, Service}
import com.twitter.finagle.http
import com.twitter.util.{Await, Future}

object HelloWorld extends App {
  val service = new Service[http.Request, http.Response] {
    def apply(req: http.Request): Future[http.Response] =
      Future.value(http.Response(req.version, http.Status.Ok))
  }
  val server = Http.serve(":8080", service)
  Await.ready(server)
}
```

WORKSPACE file

```
maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.4.4",
        "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.4.1",
        "org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.11:2.4.1",
        "org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:2.4.1",
        "org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.11:2.4.1",
        "com.twitter:finagle-http_2.12:21.8.0",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/",
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
    ]
)
```

BUILD file

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl", "scala_binary")
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

scala_binary(
    name="helloworld",
    main_class="microservices.HelloWorld",
    srcs=[
        "Main.scala",
        ],
    deps = ["spark],
)

java_library(
    name = "spark",
    exports = [
        "@maven//:com_twitter_finagle_http_2_12_21_8_0",
        ],
)
```

Working SBT dependency that was working in my initial sbt project

```
libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" %% "finagle-http" % "21.8.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue, unlike in sbt, in bazel i had induvidualy add the related dependencies. I modified the workspace as below.

```
maven_install(
artifacts = [
    "com.twitter:finagle-http_2.12:21.8.0",
    "com.twitter:util-core_2.12:21.8.0",
    "com.twitter:finagle-core_2.12:21.8.0",
    "com.twitter:finagle-base-http_2.12:21.8.0",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:2.11.2",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.2",

],
repositories = [
    "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/",
    "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
]
```

Build file --

```
java_library(
name = "finagletrial",
exports = [
    "@maven//:com_twitter_finagle_http_2_12_21_8_0",
    "@maven//:com_twitter_util_core_2_12_21_8_0",
    "@maven//:com_twitter_finagle_core_2_12_21_8_0",
    "@maven//:com_twitter_finagle_base_http_2_12_21_8_0",
    "@maven//:com_fasterxml_jackson_module_jackson_module_scala_2_12_2_11_2",
    "@maven//:com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_databind_2_11_2"
    ],
```